# Access GLSL vec4 components by ivec4 indices

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

In GLSL I can do

```
vec4 data = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
gl_FragColor = data.xxyy;
```

But can I somehow do?

```
vec4 data = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
ivec4 indices = ivec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
gl_FragColor = data[indices];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. Actually you want to [Swizzle](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) something like `data.indices`.

You have to construct a `vec4`:

```c
gl_FragColor = 
    vec4(data[indices[0]], data[indices[1]], data[indices[2]], data[indices[3]]);
```

Alternatively you can use matrix multiplication:

```c
indices = mat4(vec4(1,1,0,0), vec4(0,0,1,1), vec4(0,0,0,0), vec4(0,0,0,0));
gl_FragColor = indices * data;
```